# Distinct and Inner joins with sequelize

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

Can anyone tell me what is the best way to get the same result as this SQL query with Sequelize:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (c.id),
    c.*
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b
    ON b.id = a."table2Id" 
INNER JOIN table3 c
    ON c.id = b."table3Id"
ORDER BY c.date DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Right now, "include" give pretty much the result I need for inner join, but a "distinct" on a joined table looks way harder to get...

The goal is to join 3 tables, ordering them by the date of the third join, avoid having multiple times the same entry from the third join and finally only get the distinct entries from the third join (which will always have a "table1" relation since we started from this table to get them).

Answer (score 1):

```
Table1.findAll({ 
    attributes: [ [sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', sequelize.col('table1.table3Id')), 'c.id'] ],
    include: [ [Table2, "b"], [Table3, "c" ] ],
    order: [ [Table1.associations.Table3, 'date', 'DESC'] ],
    limit: 10
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT (b.table3Id), c.*
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b ON b.id = a."table2Id" 
INNER JOIN table3 c ON c.id = b."table3Id"
ORDER BY c.date DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. My SQL query is already working! My goal is to "translate it" to have some Sequelize code instead and being consistent with the rest of my code.